# Regular Expression Validator for accepting values like ".55488"

Tags: regex

I am using `((\d+)+(\.\d+))$` regular expression validator for accepting both numbers and decimals. It is accepting the values like:

```
212316.4654564
1.255
5455454.55
0.54446
```

But it is not accepting like `.15555`. Please give some expression to validate all types.

Answer (score 0):

This filters **decimal numbers** ([test it here](http://regex101.com/r/cB5iC0/1)):

```
^((\d+)\.(\d+))$
```

This filters **decimal numbers**, as well as **integers** ([test it here](http://regex101.com/r/aK7gZ8/1)):

```
^((\d*\.)?(\d+))$
```

This filters **decimal numbers**, as well as **integers**, with or without a **sign** ([test it here](http://regex101.com/r/qE9mT4/1)):

```
^([\-\+]?(\d*\.)?(\d+))$
```

Comment: I think you mean `^((\d+)?\.(\d+))$`

Comment: Now that the question became clearer, yes. Otherwise it would just accept integers as well as floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

simply use this :

```
((\d*)+(\.\d+))$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zU2hB5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Just make the first part not too greedy. :)

```
((\d*?)(\.\d+))$
```